# (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'**

Tags: r, machine-learning

I´m trying to make a crosstable with the gmodels library and i have this error message

> Error in CrossTable(tree_validate$diagnosis, as.integer(tree_pred), prop.chisq = FALSE) : (list) object cannot be coerced to type 'integer'

The `Tree_validate$diagnosis` format is an integer
and the `tree_pred` format is a list

```
library(gmodels)
CrossTable(tree_validate$diagnosis, tree_pred,
           prop.chisq = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `unlist` will make `tree_pred` a vector.

```
as.integer(unlist(tree_pred))
```

Or you can access a specific list item using bracket notation:

```
tree_pred[[1]]
```